# How can I create and use NSPredicate with queries in iOS's Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

How can I create and use `NSPredicate` with queries in iOS's Core Data?

Answer (score 1):

By "queries", do you mean an `NSFetchRequest`? If so, here is a simple example:

Say you have an entity named Car, and it has a license plate number named "licenceNumber" of `NSString` type.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Car" inManagedObjectContext:yourObjectContext]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"licenceNumber==%@", theLicensePlateNumberYouWant]];
```

Saying that, you may want to spend some time reading Apple's documentation first.